# How to hide taxonomy menu items on specific pages?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, routes

My situation on D7:

I have 6 different menus displayed on the left side region of a Omega theme using with Delta + Context. Each menu is a taxonomy vocabulary created using taxonomy_menu and taxonomy_menu_trails module.

These menu items are displayed in a tree format, and one item from every menu should be hidden on few specific pages only.

Let's say 'Menu 1' has 5 items:

-Term-1

--Term-2

---Term-3

---Term-4

---Term-5

where item Term-1 is linked to url: 'xyz' and when user clicks on 'A' and enters the 'xyz' page the menu item 'Term-1' should be hidden.

The link of menu item 'A' is manually updated.